# neo4j creates another same instance on selecting data

Tags: neo4j

The structure of my nodes are like this:

```
==> | Node[613]{name:"The Bigos",fs_id:"51a8e1a12fc6e7ef6d121077"}                                            
==> | Node[614]{name:"Maceraperest",fs_id:"51bafb3d498ed54bd4c7fa8c"}                                         
==> | Node[616]{name:"Viking",fs_id:"51bafe1de4b090ea9dceb20e"}                                               
==> | Node[618]{name:"Metro Gross Market",fs_id:"51bb426c498e47af428ca013"}
```

When I try to create these nodes again, a php script I wrote checks on fs_id to find that if the node already exists or not. If it exists, it returns me the node and does not create a new one.

Now the problem is that even though it does not create new nodes, the console shows me that it did.

```
==> | Node[613]{name:"The Bigos",fs_id:"51a8e1a12fc6e7ef6d121077"}                                            
==> | Node[613]{name:"The Bigos",fs_id:"51a8e1a12fc6e7ef6d121077"}                                            
==> | Node[613]{name:"The Bigos",fs_id:"51a8e1a12fc6e7ef6d121077"}                                            
==> | Node[614]{name:"Maceraperest",fs_id:"51bafb3d498ed54bd4c7fa8c"}                                         
==> | Node[614]{name:"Maceraperest",fs_id:"51bafb3d498ed54bd4c7fa8c"}                                         
==> | Node[614]{name:"Maceraperest",fs_id:"51bafb3d498ed54bd4c7fa8c"}                                         
==> | Node[616]{name:"Viking",fs_id:"51bafe1de4b090ea9dceb20e"}                                               
==> | Node[616]{name:"Viking",fs_id:"51bafe1de4b090ea9dceb20e"}                                               
==> | Node[616]{name:"Viking",fs_id:"51bafe1de4b090ea9dceb20e"}                                               
==> | Node[618]{name:"Metro Gross Market",fs_id:"51bb426c498e47af428ca013"}                                   
==> | Node[618]{name:"Metro Gross Market",fs_id:"51bb426c498e47af428ca013"}                                   
==> | Node[618]{name:"Metro Gross Market",fs_id:"51bb426c498e47af428ca013"}
```

Look at the node ids, they are same! And if I explore the node 618 for example in the data browser, it returns me a single node. Also the query

```
start n=node(618) return n;
```

also returns single row. But the query below returns multiple rows of same node id and the row count is increasing when I test the above nodes for existence.

```
start n=node(331) match n-[:BEEN]->(venues) return venues order by id(venues);
```

It might be nothing but I'm curious that if somehow Neo4j is eating extra memory for doing this or it is just something like caching system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably just have multiple `BEEN` relationships, then each of those relationships yields another result row.

If you just have one row per venue do this:

```
start n=node(331) 
match n-[:BEEN]->(venues) 
return distinct venues;
```

to see the different relationships, use:

```
start n=node(331) 
match n-[rel:BEEN]->(venues) 
return venues,collect(rel);
```

Comment: Wow. Somehow there is more than one BEEN relationship as you said.